# Charts in HTML using Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, datatables

I need to create charts in my html page using Data from tables. Tables are already created using datatables and currently I am using Highcharts to create charts from those tables.

The problem I am facing is as Highcharts is creating chart for all the columns in the table. where as I want some columns to be disabled initially when the page is loaded. or best the chart should be created for only the for those columns where header contains some string.

I am open to change to any other plugin which gives Highcharts like looks and hover capabilities.

Comment: Have a look at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping and its example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/seriesmapping-label/

Comment: Actually I checked that but since in my case I am using multiple tables on single page I have to use column names from a table based on string matching. Which I am not able to relate from that Demo. Can you please help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Only using the columns with some substring I don't think it is possible, but you have the `startColumn` and `endColumn` properties to choose a range of columns to use.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gt0bk9m7/

```
data: {
    table: 'datatable',
    endColumn: 1
},
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you reply.
I need to choose columns in between. Like 1 then 3rd the 7th.
so this can not work.
Please suggest if there is anyother plugin which provides this kind of functionality which i can use.

Comment: I don't know about any other plugin, but can't you rearrange your table columns?

Comment: No thats not possible. Table needs to be in that order only.

Comment: Well, then I suggest you to parse your data table into a series, instead of using `datatable`

Comment: Actually I am using django and already the data coming from server is huge. So if i create data series in django as well it will put more load on server again and the page size will increase.
If you can suggest me something to create data series from already created datatable using javascript or something, That will be great. Since in this case the processing will on client side.

Comment: All I think highchart does when you use a datatable is parsing the data into a series. Of course it should do it on an optimized way, but I don't think it should be much more efficient than a simple `for` through your table rows, picking the data for the series. Try it and see if it doesn't hang.